# How to show page loading without javascript?

Tags: php, usability

I'm in the middle of re-building our website for users who don't have javascript enabled (surprisingly high percentage of our visitors).

**What is the best way to show a user that something is loading without using javascript.**

Background:  Our login has to search for an email server before it logs someone in, it can sometimes take 5-10 seconds, sometimes up to twenty.

Current Thinking:  I should reload the landing page with a new button that says loading and a loader icon and then redirect that to a page that actually does the logging in with header

**Just realized I can't do this because the php reload has to be before anything is displayed on the page.**

Any ideas?  Perhaps there's onclick CSS I can use?

**Could I create a hidden form and then submit the form w/ php once the operations are finished?**

Comment: ive never used them much myself so i cant really help with specifics, but i think this can be done with output buffers http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Maybe the question should be: why is it taking so long? 5 to 10 seconds is a lot of time. Also, why is it that your visitors aren't using JS? Are you sure they are not bots or in a mobile device?
All the good javascript apps should degrade gracefully, maybe you shouldn't discard js because not all your visitors have it.

Comment: It's a product for lesser tech savvy users.  I'm redirecting everyone with js enabled to the standard site, and using this new build for non js users.  It needs to find the currect mail server - if it doesn't exist, then we need to find it.  Simple enough for yahoo or gmail, but when we need to custom search your @domain.com email address for the mailserver, it takes a lengthy amount of time to attempt to connect to your imap and then check your password.  Usually 1 second per connection attempt - and there can be multiple if we don't have your mail server on file.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers usually don't wait to receive the entire page before displaying it. So your script could echo the page headers and the beginning of the page, and display a message telling to wait the page finish to load, then display the rest of the page, according to the success or not of the authentication. At the end, there could be a javascript redirection, with an alternate redirect link for those who javascript isn't activated.

You could also try using [meta refresh tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh). Each time the page is reloaded, the script could check if the authentication is done.

Comment: Trying to build this specifically for non javascript users, so I'd like to create auto redirects without using javascript. Also, I'm fairly certain most of this group uses IE - not sure how that would affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible in the "traditional" sense of popping up a spinning 'loading' icon, since javascript is the only way to manipulate the current page without refreshing.  CSS is only used for presentation, and doesn't have any way to know if a button has been clicked.  And if most of your users are on IE, there's not much chance of the more 'advanced' CSS features working, anyway.

All of that said, your initial thought would work (on further thought, maybe not?).  Use a landing page with a loading icon and "please wait" text, which includes the login logic, then re-direct to the website itself, using a meta refresh (or 302 redirect) with the timeout of 20 seconds (or the approximate maximum value it would take to log someone in).

Combining this with Charles answer would probably work.  Display a 20 second time out meta refresh header with the basic loading page, then have the PHP for the login below that in the source file.

Comment: Could I have a form and then submit it using curl or something similar to redirect to the new page with post data?

Comment: Curl is serverside... but you might actually be able to use that on the 'please wait, loading' landing page to start the login process, you could use that in combination with a short meta-refresh (back to the landing page) to constantly check if the user has successfully logged in, and if so, then refresh to the proper website.

Answer (score 0):

for reloading without javascript you can use the meta refresh

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://example.com/">
```

the login form will redirect user to some page with the loading message and loader icon, the real url will be loaded after 5 seconds for example
after those 5 seconds, if the login process isn't done yet (some if-else logic in your serverside script), the page with loading message and loader icon will continue to be showed

without javascript you can still do a lot of thing, but it's much trickier
there are even some ajax-without-javascript techniques...

Comment: I'm going to take a look at this - only thought in my head is that it will disrupt the existing php operation.

Comment: sorry, i didn't read your question enough... if you use the meta-refresh so the login must be processed background and working with session in that case will be such a pain...